# Keras : How to merge layers sequentially not use "concatenate"

Tags: keras, merge, lstm, layer

I'm trying to build a model that combines cnn and lstm.
I want to multivariate the input of cnn and put the outputs sequentially into the input of the LSTM. However, there is a problem in merging the cnn outputs. If you use concatenate, it will stretch to axis = -1 as shown. But I'll put it in the lstm structure so I'd like to increase it sequentailly. But I didn't find any function to merge except concatenate. The shape I want is (None, 6, 1904) in the image below. What can I do?

below is my build code.

```
def build_model():
    in_layers, out_layers = [], []
    for i in range(in_len):
        inputs = Input(shape=(row,col, channel))
        conv1 = Conv2D(4, (12, 12), activation='relu')(inputs)
        pool1 = pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4,4))(conv1)
        conv2 = Conv2D(4, (7, 7) , activation='relu')(pool1)
        pool2 = pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3))(conv2)
        conv3 = Conv2D(8, (5, 5) , activation='relu')(pool2)
        pool3 = pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv3)
        flat = Flatten()(pool3)
        # store layers
        in_layers.append(inputs)
        out_layers.append(flat)
        print(type(flat))
    merged = concatenate(out_layers)
    model = Model(inputs=in_layers, outputs=merged)
    plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='cnn_lstm_real.png')

    return model
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is still concatenation, but on a different, new axis. The concatenation layer and function allows to specify the axis, so you can do it like this:

```
def build_model():
    in_layers, out_layers = [], []
    for i in range(in_len):
        inputs = Input(shape=(row,col, channel))
        conv1 = Conv2D(4, (12, 12), activation='relu')(inputs)
        pool1 = pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4,4))(conv1)
        conv2 = Conv2D(4, (7, 7) , activation='relu')(pool1)
        pool2 = pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3,3))(conv2)
        conv3 = Conv2D(8, (5, 5) , activation='relu')(pool2)
        pool3 = pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(conv3)
        flat = Flatten()(pool3)
        flat = Reshape((1, -1))(flat)
        # store layers
        in_layers.append(inputs)
        out_layers.append(flat)

    merged = concatenate(out_layers, axis = 1)
    model = Model(inputs=in_layers, outputs=merged)
    plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, to_file='cnn_lstm_real.png')

    return model
```

The only big difference is that you need to add the new axis explicitly in the output of each branch (hence the `Reshape` layer), in order to allow for concatenation to happen along that axis.